# How to get the parent element id in the following function

Tags: jquery

I need to get the id of parent element in the same function and console

I tried to get the id of my parent element with which I bind the function

```
$('#customized-player').mediaelementplayer({
        alwaysShowControls: true,
        features: ['progress', 'duration', 'tracks' ],
        audioVolume: 'horizontal',
        audioWidth: 450,
        timeFormat: 'mm:ss',
        startVolume: .6,
        success: function (instance) {
            var thisID = $(this).parents(".audio-player").attr('id');
            console.log("Parent ID is:" + thisID);

        }
    });
```

I want to get the id of parent element of this "#customized-player" as you will see in the code above. I've initialize a variable with name "thisID", please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about `$(this).closest(".audio-player").attr('id')` ? and also what'ts `$(this)`? can you `console.log($(this));` it could refer to current function not the element. please make sure you know what `$(this)` is.

Comment: Getting "undefined", is I am trying code in the right place?

Comment: what about `$('#customized-player').closest('.audio-player.).attr('id);`

Comment: Also you can only have ONE element with ID "customized-player" - and if you have, then no need to look it up in the success

Comment: @AndrejsGubars I need to get this dynamically done. So you are right about $(this). Can I get this "#customized-player" in a variable inside a function? or any other suitable way to get in the id from here "$('#customized-player').mediaelementplayer({" in the variable?

Comment: If you only have one, then `$('#customized-player').closest('.audio-player.).attr('id);` will work anywhere

Comment: @mplungjan I've some code in the success function too... I just need to get the parent id of with which I bind this function ".mediaelementplayer(", I would be glad if you please respond with code sample?

Comment: @AndrejsGubars I am getting my desired thing with this:
"$("##customized-player").closest(".audio-player").attr('id')" but I want this dynamically. under "$('#customized-player').mediaelementplayer({" with $(this).. is there any optimal way?

Comment: I don't understand you, dynamically what? `this` is referring to the `mediaelementplayer` instance not the `element`.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair Do you have more than one player on the page and that is why you need to see what the ID of the parent is? IDs must be unique

Comment: @mplungjan exactly, I've more than one player on the page and I want to get the parent id of each.

Comment: then you cannot use id's. you must use classes, thats what they were designed for. https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the reference https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/usage.md#jquery update your `success` function as below.

```
$('#customized-player').mediaelementplayer({
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    features: ['progress', 'duration', 'tracks' ],
    audioVolume: 'horizontal',
    audioWidth: 450,
    timeFormat: 'mm:ss',
    startVolume: .6,
    success: function (mediaElement, originalNode, instance) {
        var thisID = $(originalNode).parents(".audio-player").attr('id');
        console.log("Parent ID is:" + thisID);
    }
});
```

Comment: this works, but i guess the OP mentions the fact that he is having more than 1 element with `id="customized-player"` which should not be the case.

Comment: @AndrejsGubars If OP is using id selector `('#customized-player')` then jquery will always return first element, So he has to update it to some `class` selector instead of `id`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their time and valuable comments. this sort out my problem "var thisID = $(originalNode).parents(".audio-player").attr('id');"
again thanks to everyone for their precious time and help